# PostgreSQL - "Ten most frequent entries"

Tags: sql, postgresql

- We've got a table with two colums: USER and MESSAGE
- An USER can have more than one message.
- The table is frequently updated with more USER-MESSAGE pairs.

I want to frequently retrieve the top X users that sent the most messages. What would be the optimal (DX and performnce wise) solution for it?

The solutions I see myself:

- I could GROUP BY and COUNT, however it doesn't seem like the most performant nor clean solution.
- I could keep an additional table that'd keep count of every user's messages. On every message insertion into the main table, I could also update the relevant row here. Could the update be done automaticaly? Perhaps I could write a procedure for it?
- For the main table, I could create a VIEW that'd have an additional "calculated" column - it'd GROUP BY and COUNT, but again, it's probably not the most performant solution. I'd query the view instead.

Please tell me whatever you think might be the best solution.

Comment: I'd start with a view, doing GROUP BY etc. Will always have consistent data (is that important?) Do you need instant updates, or will once per day be fine too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and third solutions are essentially the same, since a view is nothing but a “crystallized” query.

The second solution would definitely make for faster queries, but at the price of storing redundant data. The disadvantages of such an approach are:

- You are running danger of inconsistent data. You can reduce that danger somewhat by using triggers that automatically keep the data synchronized.
- The performance of modifications of `message` will be worse, because the trigger will have to be executed, and each modification will also modify `users` (that is the natural place to keep such a count).

The decision should be based on the question whether the `GROUP BY` query will be fast enough for your purposes. If yes, use it and avoid the above disadvantages. If not, consider storing the extra count.

Answer (score 2):

Some databases have incrementally updated views, where you create a view like in your example 3, and it automatically keeps it updated like in your example 2.  PostgreSQL does not have this feature.

For your option 1, it seems pretty darn clean to me.  Hard to get much simpler than that.  Yes, it could have performance problems, but how fast do you really need it to be?  You should make sure you actually have a problem before worrying about solving it.

For your option 2, what you are looking for is a trigger.  For each insertion, it would increment a count in the user table.  If you ever delete, you would also need to decrease the count.  Also, if ever update to change the user of an existing entry, the trigger would need to decrease the count of the old user and increase it of the new user.  This will decrease the concurrency, as if two processes try to insert messages from the same user at the same time, one will block until the other finishes.  This may not matter much to you.  Also, the mere existence of triggers imposes some CPU overhead, plus whatever the trigger itself actually does.  But unless our server is already overloaded, this might not matter.

Your option 3 doesn't make much sense to me, at least not in PostgreSQL.  There is no performance benefit, and it would act to obscure rather than clarify what is going on.  Anyone who can't understand a GROUP BY is probably going to have even more problems understanding a view which exists only to do a GROUP BY.

Another option is a materialized view.  But you will see stale data from them between refreshes.  For some uses that is acceptable, for some it is not.